# If I have two hard disks, can hard disk 1 be /dev/sda on one boot while being /dev/sdb on another boot?

Tags: linux

Say I have two hard disks in my computer.

Now when I boot into my OS, the two hard disks will be represented by the following two files:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
```

My question is, is there any guarantee that hard disk 1 will always be `/dev/sda` and not `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: I think that's dependent on BIOS, and possibly disk spin-up speed, but I'm not sure.  Usually one uses UUIDs to remove ambiguity

Comment: You could possibly write appropriate `udev` rules to make the one true "first" disk appear as `sda` but it might be easier to go by UUID or labels or something...

Comment: Also, `/dev/sd*` are not _files_; they are _block devices_.

Comment: @DopeGhoti "mknod - make block or character special files".  I'd say `/dev/sd*` are _files representing block devices_

Comment: Use one of the various `/dev/disk/by-*` symlinks instead of `/dev/sd*`, they are guaraneed to be consistent across boots. Assign UUIDs to partitions if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Although the assignments rarely change, you don't have 100% guarantee that the first HDD will be `/dev/sda`.

For this, you need to refer to the HDD by UUID and not by device. Hence in `/etc/fstab` you'll need to put entries like

```
UUID=0a3407de-0aab-458b-b5c1-842212a327a3  /foo  ext4   defaults  
UUID=b411d319-f0a0-4c87-9e05-184900ae8539  /bar  ext4   defaults
```

instead of

```
/dev/sda                                   /foo  ext4   defaults  
/dev/sdb                                   /bar  ext4   defaults
```

Use the command

```
blkid
```

to get the UUID of all your mounted devices.